# Code flow through callback in java script

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js, chord-diagram

```
-----------------File1.html-------------------------

      <body>
        <div id="tooltip"></div>
        <script src="lib/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mapper.js"></script>
        <script>
        d3.json('data/readme.json', function (error, data) {
            var mpr = chordMpr(data);
            _.each(data, function (elem) {
              mpr.addToMap(name(elem.name))
            })

            mpr.setFilter(function (row, a, b) {
            /*  alert(JSON.stringify(a) +"-------"+JSON.stringify(row)+"-------"+JSON.stringify(b));
                alert(a.name + "--" + row.name + "--" + b.name); */
                return (name(row.name) === a.name)
              })
              .setAccessor(function (recs, a, b) {

                if (!recs[0]) return 0;
                var n = 0;
                _.each(recs, function (r) {
                    //alert(r.imports)
                  _.each(r.imports, function (i) {
                     // alert(JSON.stringify(b) + "----" + i);
                    if (name(i) === b.name) n++;
                  });
                });
                return n;
              });
            alert(/* "*****" + mpr.getMatrix() + "-----" + */ JSON.stringify(mpr.getMap()));
            drawChords(mpr.getMatrix(), mpr.getMap());
          });

          function name(name) {
            return name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")).substring(6);
          }

---------------------------File1.html-----------------------------


------------------------------mapper.js---------------------------
//*******************************************************************
//  CHORD MAPPER 
//*******************************************************************
function chordMpr (data) {
    alert(data + "kimi is faster than you");
  var mpr = {}, mmap = {}, n = 0,
      matrix = [], filter, accessor;

  mpr.setFilter = function (fun) {
      alert("inside filter");
    filter = fun;
    return this;
  },
  mpr.setAccessor = function (fun) {
    accessor = fun;
    return this;
  },
  mpr.getMatrix = function () {
    matrix = [];
    _.each(mmap, function (a) {
      if (!matrix[a.id]) matrix[a.id] = [];
      _.each(mmap, function (b) {
       var recs = _.filter(data, function (row) {
          return filter(row, a, b);
        })
        matrix[a.id][b.id] = accessor(recs, a, b);
      });
    });
    return matrix;
  },
  mpr.getMap = function () {
    return mmap;
  },
  mpr.printMatrix = function () {
    _.each(matrix, function (elem) {
      console.log(elem);
    })
  },
  mpr.addToMap = function (value, info) {
    if (!mmap[value]) {
      mmap[value] = { name: value, id: n++, data: info }
    }
  },
  mpr.addValuesToMap = function (varName, info) {
      alert("inside addValuesToMap  " + varName + info);
    var values = _.uniq(_.pluck(data, varName));
    alert(values);
    //values is the list of countries in the importer[i] column in CSV form
    _.map(values, function (v) {
        //v is individual country in the importer[i] column
      if (!mmap[v]) {
        mmap[v] = { name: v, id: n++, data: info }
      }
    });
    return this;
  }
  return mpr;
}
//*******************************************************************
//  CHORD READER
//*******************************************************************
function chordRdr (matrix, mmap) {
  return function (d) {
    var i,j,s,t,g,m = {};
    if (d.source) {
      i = d.source.index; j = d.target.index;
      s = _.where(mmap, {id: i });
      t = _.where(mmap, {id: j });
      m.sname = s[0].name;
      m.sdata = d.source.value;
      m.svalue = +d.source.value;
      m.stotal = _.reduce(matrix[i], function (k, n) { return k + n }, 0);
      m.tname = t[0].name;
      m.tdata = d.target.value;
      m.tvalue = +d.target.value;
      m.ttotal = _.reduce(matrix[j], function (k, n) { return k + n }, 0);
    } else {
      g = _.where(mmap, {id: d.index });
      m.gname = g[0].name;
      m.gdata = g[0].data;
      m.gvalue = d.value;
    }
    m.mtotal = _.reduce(matrix, function (m1, n1) { 
      return m1 + _.reduce(n1, function (m2, n2) { return m2 + n2}, 0);
    }, 0);
    return m;
  }
}
```

I am having difficulty in analysing the code flow in the above code. 
In the mpr.setFilter(function (row, a, b)) call, what are row, a and b? I can't find any variables by this name. Also how are the calls translating from one function to other.
Please help.

Comment: row, a, and b are argument names for the anonymous function expression which is a parameter to the setFilter method of mpr

Comment: Can you please explain in detail.......how row,a and b are getting intialised?

Comment: they are function arguments, they get "initialised" when the function is called - p.s. I wont be going into detail, that would require an "answer", and I don't have a full answer

Answer (score 1):

`setFilter` is a function which takes an argument of a function that is stored to a "member" variable `filter`.  When the user calls `setFilter` and passes their function they must know the **contract** that it takes three arguments.  These are your `row`, `a`, and `b` arguments, they aren't assigned here, just there to make the function match later on.

If you trace this a little further that anonymous function passed into `setFilter` and stored in the variable `filter` is then called in the `getMatrix` function in mapper.js.  You'll see when it is called the arguments of `row`, `a` and `b` are passed in.

Ain't JavaScript fun?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the contract part? If I print the variables "a", "b" and "row" through alert, I am getting their values.

Comment: @davyjones, by contract, I simply meant that the developer using `mapper.js` has to know the function signature of `filter` in order to pass the correct number of arguments.

Comment: I'm still having trouble in figuring out how the values are getting assigned. Also, how and why are the 3 parameters being passed to filter variable? As far as I can see, it has been declared as a variable, not a function. Please help.

Comment: `filter` is a variable.  It's a variable holding a reference to a function.  This is very common in JavaScript.  The `filter` function isn't execute until this line:  `return filter(row, a, b);`, at this point it's executed with `row`, `a` and `b` passed in and then the return value of filter is returned from `getMatrix`.